# Load InboundReferencedBeans for Insight add-on in JIRA

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm working on Insight automation groovy script, but I got stuck in one point.

I have Insight object called "**Agreement**".

This object has Inbound References called "Services".

Each Agreement can have any number of Services. I need to get list of all Services for any Agreement. I found the method `findObjectInboundReferencedBeans(int id)` in the docs, but apparently, I'm missing something as when I run the script, I get an error in log:

> **AutomationRuleGroovyScriptAction, Unexpected error: No signature of method: com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.impl.ObjectFacadeImpl.findObjectInboundReferencedBeans() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [15748]**

Here is my script:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectAttributeBean;
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectBean;
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.MutableObjectAttributeBean;
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.MutableObjectBean;

Class objectFacadeClass = ComponentAccessor.getPluginAccessor().getClassLoader().findClass("com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.ObjectFacade")
def objectFacade = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(objectFacadeClass)

// def agreementStatusId = 2641
// def serviceStatusId = 2180
// def activeStatus = 1
// def stoppedStatus = 6

def attributeRef = "Status smlouvy"

def objectKey = object.getObjectKey();
def insightObject = objectFacade.loadObjectBean(objectKey)
int objectId = insightObject.getId()

----------------------------------

**// Here is the line I need help with
def inRef = objectFacade.findObjectInboundReferencedBeans(objectId)**

----------------------------------

def objectAttribute = objectFacade.loadObjectAttributeBean(objectId, attributeRef)
def objectAttributeValue = objectAttribute.getObjectAttributeValueBeans()[0].getValue()

log.warn(objectKey.toString())
log.warn(insightObject.toString())
log.warn(inRef)
```

I use this script also to get attribute value from Agreement object, which works fine.

I guess the problem is that I call the method on wrong object, but when I try to call in dirrectly on "insightObject" , I got the same error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As answered on the [Atlassian Community Page](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Service-Management/Load-InboundReferenced-Beans-for-Insight/qaq-p/1830542).

The method was removed with the release of Insight 5.1, see the upgrade notes [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/insightapps/insight-5-1-release-notes-1085194664.html#Insight5.1releasenotes-BeforeupgradingtoInsight5.1).

However, you can just use this to solve your issue:

```
def inRef = iqlFacade.findObjects(/object HAVING outboundReferences(Key = ${objectKey})/)
```